# Paypal Adaptive: Should it be used considering it is under limited release?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

For setting up a transaction between Paypal account to another Paypal account without user intervention/permission, I was  planning to integrate Paypal Adaptive but had second thoughts due to a note on the Paypal's web page for Adaptive payments. The screen shot and link of the note attached below:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Screenshot:
[image]

This got me to wondering whether Adaptive is a good choice for new integrations considering the limited release note or whether I would be able to make requests in a live account currently? (It works in sandbox account currently)
If yes, then should I be worried there may be some future update that would render my integration to not work?
If its not a good choice then what other alternatives does Paypal offer that are best suitable for Paypal account to account transaction?

Initially, I was actually trying to integrate PreApprove coupled with Pay API for automated transactions without user intervention/permission but used "DoReference" instead due to this note from Paypal.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I've been working on an app for about two years that uses the PayPal MPL and adaptive payments to facilitate transactions from one user to another.  I just saw that PayPal has moved adaptive payments into a "limited release," and that new apps will require prior approval from PayPal.  My app is already listed under my develper page on PayPal, and it works in sandbox mode.  Trying to decide if I should continue with adaptive payments, or try some alternative (if there is one).

Comment: @KevinBright did you figure your issue out?

OP?

Comment: @tonino.j I stuck with the MPL.  I was already authorized because I registered my app before the limited release issue, and I don't think what I wanted to do could be done with anything other than the MPL.